# Probability that a coin was a fair coin

Tags: probability

There are three coins in a box. When tossed, one of the coins comes up heads only 30%
of the time, one of the coins is fair, and the third comes up heads 80% of the time. A coin
is selected at random from the box and tossed three times. If two heads and a tail come up
in this order (HHT) what is the probability that the coin was the fair coin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Use Bayes Rule.
$$\
P(Fair|HHT) = \frac{P(HHT|Fair)*P(Fair)}{P(HHT|coin1)*P(coin1)+P(HHT|coin2)*P(coin2)+P(HHT|coin3)*P(coin3)}
$$

Comment: thanks.. it really helped

Answer (score 1):

This might be naive, but my instinct is to say
$\frac{(0.5)^3}{(0.3)^2 (0.7)+(0.5)^3+(0.8)^2 (0.2)} = \frac{125}{316}$.

Comment: That looks good to me.  It is Bayes Law, stripped clean.

Answer (score 0):

Let $C$ be random variable representing the coin chosen. Notice $C$ is uniformly distributed over $\{1,2,3\}$, ie. $$\mathbb P(C=1)=\mathbb P(C=2)=\mathbb P(C=3) = 1/3.$$

Denote by $A$ the event of observing the outcome $HHT$. You are being asked to compute $\mathbb P(C=2\mid A)$. Using Bayes' rule,

\begin{aligned}
\mathbb P(C=2\mid A) & = \frac{\mathbb P(A\mid C = 2)\mathbb P(C)}{\mathbb P(A)}.
\end{aligned}

From here, the only tricky part is computing
$$
\mathbb P(A) = \sum_{i=1}^3\mathbb P\left(A\mid C=i\right)\mathbb P\left(C=i\right),
$$
but now you have all the ingredients to do so.